# How to add editable first child node in winforms

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview which represents filesystem, I have a New folder button, It works fine if the selected node has some child nodes, however when selected node does not have any child nodes it is not able to add a editable child node. I am using the following code:

```
tree.LabelEdit = true;
TreeNode node = new TreeNode("New Folder");
if(tree.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count>0)
   tree.SelectedNode.Expand();

tree.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(node);

if(tree.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count>0)
   tree.SelectedNode.Expand();
node.BeginEdit();
```

Any ideas on whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change two lines in your code like that:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   tree.SelectedNode = tree.Nodes.Add("Hello", "Hello");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tree.LabelEdit = true;
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode("New Folder");
    tree.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(node);
    tree.SelectedNode.Expand();
    node.BeginEdit();
}
```

**Explanation:** You cannot expand a node which hasn't child nodes. So you have to add the node *before* you expand the parent node.

Comment: @NitinChaudhari: There must be an error elsewhere. Do you have subscribed some events of treeview? I've tested the code above and it works!

Comment: I have BeforeExpand and AfterLabelEdit, but it doesnt break in afterlabeledit, can you please email me your working sample?

Comment: @NitinChaudhari: I've changed the sample code in my answer. I have a form with a treeview and a button on it. I think you have to search the problem in the BeforeExpand code. Post it and I take a look at it.

Comment: You were right, BeforeExpand was clearing all nodes, now if i dont have any subdirectories i am not clearing it. Its working now. Thanks :)